# initializing of sisterclass with inherited constructor

Tags: inheritance, c++11, constructor

I have a base class which is inherited by 2 child classes. This child classes also inherit the constructor's. But if I try to construct instance of class A with a copy of class B it won't work (compile error).

```
class base {
  int a_;
public:
  base(int x)
  : a_(x) {}

  base(base const& cpy)
  : a_(cpy.a_) {}
};

class A : public base {
public:
  using base::base;
};

class B : public base  {
public:
  using base::base;
};

int main() {
    A a(123);
    B b(a);

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fbd01cd7eba8cd0).

However, if I insert a constructor with the base as parameter class it works:

```
class A : public base  {
public:
  using base::base;

  A(base const& cpy)
  : base(cpy) {}
};
```

It's not a problem to insert a constructor for the base. My question is why is the inherited constructor not working.

Comment: Yeah, I removed my comment because it has come to my attention that the only reason it "worked" for me was due to MVP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy constructor (and move, and default) are specifically excluded from inheritance. I think they wanted to avoid making implicit the kind of reverse-slicing behavior you demonstrate, although in many cases it's not a problem.

N3797 §12.9/2:

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors other than a constructor having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless …

Comment: i think, this is what i was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

If base class had done deep copy everywhere it would expect the same from inherited classes. 
However, if we started doing default copy ctors then the compiler would fail to "automate" it because you'd need to write special code in all classes for it.

Your example is fairly easy but it will be difficult if you had multiple pointers and variables in derived classes.
Perhaps that is why it was never allowed in the beginning.

Comment: Copy constructors are defined implicitly. The issue here is that the "copied-from" object is only a base. Variables in the derived class will be default-initialized unless initializers are specified for them, which is always what happens with inheriting constructors.